# Is it possible to convert android app to blackberry app?

Tags: android, blackberry

Is it possible to convert an android app to blackberry app?
I read that it's possible on Blackberry PlayBook, with limitations but it can be possible.
I would like to know if i can convert an android smartphone app to run in a blackberry smartphone.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no straight way to convert an android application to a BlackBerry smartphone application that runs RIM OS operating system. The most recent version of RIM OS is 7.1.

But for BB 10 devices it is announced that these devices and [BB 10 OS will support Android applications](http://www.brighthand.com/default.asp?newsID=18543&news=blackberry+10+android+player+RIM).

Answer (score 1):

Blackberry 10 & Playbook run on the QNX operating system.  They provide the Android runtime environment for loading Android applications.

Blackberry smartphones that use OS version 7 or earlier run on Blackberry's java JVM instead and do not support Android at all.

There will be many limitations while porting your code on BB10 or Playbook. 
Like version should be at least 2.3, widgets will not be supported.

You can get detail on this url:
    https://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_software_features.html

Answer (score -1):

Here you can do it!
https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa/

Comment: Yes, but, is it only for PlayBook OS(Tablet) or can i install after in a Blackberry Smartphone?

Comment: I think thats only for tablets playbook, but I would advise you to try it out!

Comment: Thanks, i will try it and post the results here.

Comment: You cannot install Android apps onto BBOS 7 or earlier phones. They don't have the Android environment. Only the Playbook tablet and BB10 phones have that.

Answer (score -1):

Information on the runtime for Android Apps for the new BlackBerry 10 devices is available at https://developer.blackberry.com/android/