# Is developing a BlackBerry app similar to Android?

Tags: java, android, blackberry, blackberry-10

I'm almost done building my first android app and I was looking at making a version for Blackberry. Now since Blackberry native language is Java like Android, is easier to make a blackberry version of your android app from your android code? Is there a way to port it? (Not using the runtime software. More like porting the code to blackberry os standards) Will there be code that is reusable? I'm going to download the SDK soon and read their apis and stuff later but before I did that I just wanted to know about the similarities between developing an android app and a blackberry one.

Comment: Which BlackBerry OS versions are you hoping to target?  10?  5/6/7?

Comment: @Nate Blackberry OS 10

Comment: Primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 7):

I also came from Android development, and now I'm learning Cascades for BB10. I don't know anything about BB7 though.

If you want to make an Android port you have [Repackaging tools](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/)

- [Eclipse and Android studio Plug-in](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/): this will add a few things to eclipse, and it's similar to Android launch. I suggest you use this if you port.
- Online Packager: no longer available. Please use command line tools
- [Command-line Tools](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/plugin_and_cmdlne_tools.html): self explanatory. [Download here (check website if dead link!)](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/downloads/fetch/CommandLineTools_2.0.6.201409181326-windows.zip)

While porting Android app is easier, we're usually not too happy with them. Native apps look a lot better and work faster! Then again, we prefer a port then no app. I have 3200 downloads on Google Play and 2200 on BlackBerry World on a port (it's longer on google!), and I am considering rewriting it in Cascades.

If you want to write FOR BB10.. a few options here:

- [**Native/Cascades**](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/): good looking, fast and reliable. You can either make design in QML or C++ (Qt), or both at the same time. Small things are normally written in QML, since it supports Javascript, heavy duty is in c++ (Qt).
- [**HTML5**](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/): self explanatory
- [**Native/Core**](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/getting_started.html): C/C++
- [Adobe AIR](https://developer.blackberry.com/air/) - Discontinued as of 10.3.1

You can't make Java apps for BB10. It will take some time to get used to BB10 way of working but it's worth it. I prefer Cascades over Android for design making, since those XML layouts have a mind of its own.

Edit: links fixed on 17.1.2014

Comment: Thanks man. This is great. I might port the app to BB 10 when I release the android app just to have a presence on BB and then take my time to rewrite the BB app natively or by using cascades.

Comment: Use this to identify platform in Android: `if (System.getProperty("os.name").equals("qnx")) 
   isBlackberry = true;`

Answer (score 2):

Porting apps from the Native NDK in Android over to BlackBerry is relatively simple. You can either port it directly into Eclipse or you can use runtime tools. Check out the following link with a plethora of tools to use:

https://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/

Answer (score 1):

Blackberry uses c++/qt in its current version (10)

http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/getting_started.html

but it can sideload android apps (emulate them) so it might just simply work

http://crackberry.com/how-run-almost-any-android-233-app-blackberry-10

For older versions of blackberry OS (6 and 7), check out the links provided in the other answers and also this question:

[Is it possible to convert android app to blackberry app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193372/is-it-possible-to-convert-android-app-to-blackberry-app)

Answer (score 1):

For BlackBerry10 you only need to convert it
But for Older BlackBerry OS, the java os7,  you need to rewrite code, because different with Android

Comment: OP asked for code porting, not running the APK on BB10. And if that's (mainly) true that an APK converted to a BAR will run on BB10, it's clearly not the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Using the packager

Before you begin: Follow these steps to install the Android SDK and SDK platform 4.2.2 APIs. Note that you don’t need to install Eclipse or the BlackBerry Plug-in for Android Development to use the online packager.

To repackage an app using the BlackBerry Packager is as simple as completing the following steps:

1.Set the permissions to allow your browser to run the packager applet.

2.Run the compatibility test to determine whether your app is likely to run on a BlackBerry device.

3.BlackBerry ID token and configure your computer

4.Package and sign your app.

Get started with the online packager http://developer.blackberry.com/android/bpaa